# Conditinally rendering text using Angular clipboard

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to implement a simple copy-to-clipboard function in my Angular application.

The function to copy works, however, I do not understand how conditional statements in Angular as most of my experience is in React.

In React I would define my variable

`[copy, setCopy] = useState(false)`

Then, I would pass this into wherever I want to change the text or graphic element:

`<button>{copy ? "click to copy" : "url copied"}</button>`

Using the Angular docs, this is what my copy function looks like in Angular:

```
export class ThankyouComponent {

copied = false

value ='https://url.com'

}
```

And here is where I want to use it in my HTML file

`<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="value">{{SOME_EVENT ? "copy url" : "url copied" }}</button>`

How do I access the click event of cdkCopyToClipboard in order to conditionally render the string within the button as in my React example? I've been looking around online and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to display something conditionally inside an HTML template in Angular, you can use property that holds text

In HTML button attribute you can add

```
(click)="myOnClickMethod()"
```

Which calls method inside ts file whenever click event occures.

And in that method (that should belong to ts file in the same component you can do something like which changes button text to anything you want after the click.

```
@Component({
  // Omitted for simplicity
})
export class MyComponent{
  public buttonText: string = 'Copy url'

  public myOnClickMethod(): void {
    this.buttonText = 'Copied'
  }
}
```

Then you can pass that variable with string interpolation to that button content like

```
<button ...>{{ buttonText }}</button>
```

**Bonus**

If you want to display some blocks conditionally, like some kind of fallback in case of no data, for example, in React you would probably do something like

```
if(!props.myList || props.myList.length < 1) return <strong>No data</strong>

return <> // some processing </>
```

In Angular you can use `*ngIf` directive

```
<div *ngIf="myList?.length > 0 else no-data">
 // some processing
</div>

<ng-template #no-data>
 <strong>No data</strong>
</ng-template>
```

Of course you don´t need to use else statement and you can use opposite condition in other `*ngIf` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution to my problem. I took your code and added it to my ts component. In the end my button looks like this: ```<button class="cpButton" [cdkCopyToClipboard]="value" (click)="myOnClickMethod()"> {{buttonText}}</button>```